# Knex: Escaping " as " in query conditions

Tags: knex.js

I have the following Knex code:

```js
const alias = " as 1";
knex("foo")
    .innerJoin(`bar as ${alias}`, "foo.id", `${alias}.foo_id`)
    .where(`${alias}.id`, 1);
```

and it generates the following SQL (linebreaks added for readability):

```sql
select *
from "foo"
inner join "bar" as "as 1"
    on "foo"."id" = "" as "1.foo_id"
where "" as "1.id" = ?
```

which gives a syntax error.

I'm using PostgreSQL.

What I'd like to achieve, is that in the JOIN condition `"" as "1.foo_id"` would be escaped as `" as 1"."foo_id"`, and similarly in the WHERE condition. Is this something that Knex can do, or should I use some other tool to escape the strings before giving them to Knex?

Also, I'm wondering if this is intended behavior or a bug, since e.g. changing to `const alias = "as 1"` works as expected and produces:

```sql
select *
from "foo"
inner join "bar" as "as 1"
    on "foo"."id" = "as 1"."foo_id"
where "as 1"."id" = ?
```

Edit: fixed typos

Comment: if the alias is coming from the userinput, then you can maybe split the alias and then extract the value from it.